# Java regex confused with two conditions

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, matching

The first if condition should be true if it encounters this kind sequence e.g, 1,2,3...9 except 0 and it only allows 1 digit to pass. The second if is true if it has this sequence 12, 22, 33 .. 99 except for 01,02...09. It only allows two digits to be passed. But for some reason the first condition allows two or more digits and it doesn't go to the next condition.

```
Pattern num1 = Pattern.compile("([1-9&&[^0]]){1}");
Matcher matchNum1 = num1.matcher(min);

Pattern num2 = Pattern.compile("[1-9[^0]]{2}");
Matcher matchNum2 = num2.matcher(min);


if (matchNum1.find()) {
   System.out.println("contains number and no trailing zeroes " + min );
}
else if (matchNum2.find()) {
    System.out.println("contains 2 numbers " + min);
}
else {
    System.out.println("No match");
}
```

Comment: for your second condition http://regex101.com/r/rD1dZ9/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexes will not do what you need. See the following regexes:

```
Pattern num1 = Pattern.compile("^[1-9]$");
Pattern num2 = Pattern.compile("^[1-9]\\d$");
```

> - `^` Asserts position at start of the string.
>  - `[1-9]` Match a single character in the range between 1 and 9.
>  *- `\d` Match a digit [0-9]. Elegant meta-character notation.*
>
>  - `$` Asserts position at end of the string.

Comment: ^ means start and $ means end of a line.

Comment: @Unihedron does your code satisfies the second condition?

Comment: @UniHedron no its ok, i couldn't find it in oracle java regex doc section. But I'll just google the keywords you mentioned :)